AWS lambda serverless framework on local with other aws services
I am pretty new to AWS and trying to creating AWS lambda application using node js and serverless framework. But I stumbled upon a point where I have to run the things locally  to test the things like dynamo db , SNS, S3 etc. What is the proper way to do the things in local. If there is any article or tutorial like github links which could help me with situation, Please share it
What is the correct way to do the development with aws serverless framework with other AWS services in local.

Why?  While this is possible you're going to spend a good amount of time getting this working.  You can run a Lambda locally for development and it can access things like DynamoDB, etc. that live on AWS.

yes that is good option but if we wanted to change the DB schema and do a check we can't even do with all the data in live environment right?, that's why I wanted to know if there is a local setup so to check things like this without affecting anything in the live.

If you're developing against your production environment you've got way bigger challenges.  I recognize that costs are higher with multiple environments in AWS but it will depend on how much time you want to put into this.  If you miss something locally then you've got a different issue.

Agreed .Thank for the insight which gives me new perspective.

Yes, this the use case of localstack , you can test your developpement locally :

Github repo : https://github.com/localstack/localstack
Docs for supported services : https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/feature-coverage/
tutorial for Node JS : https://docs.localstack.cloud/tutorials/elb-load-balancing/

Hoping this help.
@Vikneswaran, @stanislav-tarasenko localstack was my first answer to this but:
bellow is another approach for Lambda local devloppement and testing by proxying the requests to AWS services.
I didn't check try this but it sounds to be another approach to test your Lambda if you have a sandbox / dev account as stanislav suggested.
https://docs.sst.dev/live-lambda-development

Localstack looks like a interesting choice to do the development, although I have question, Will it be same as AWS so when I change the ENV variables and the pointing URL to live , Won't it break when I am deploying my project to AWS ?

I appreciate  @Med Agou's answer and he is right, Localstack can help you in some use cases. On the other hand, not all services can be run locally and you may stack at some point.
I would recommend running your dev tests on the real AWS account like a sandbox. In the initial stage, it requires extra efforts in IaC but the testing process will be more stable and you will not need to maintain infra in two places.
A good solution is:

Write terraform definitions for infra, so you can easily  (re-)deploy the environment and copy it immediately if you need one more (DEV, TEST, PERF, PROD, whatever...)

Prepare CI/CD for your lambda function(-s) so you can update the function automatically. There are many options to deploy Lambda function code:



2.1. zip file -> Lambda function
2.2. zip file -> S3 bucket -> Lambda function (better versioning)
2.3. Docker image -> ECR -> Lambda function (More efforts in the beginning but better option for cold start)

 One more benefit of this solution is that you test functions in a real environment and reduce potential misconfigurations.

Thanks! @Stanislav for the detailed steps, Will definitely try that way.
